# Prolog: Initialize predicate variables connected with operators correctly

Tags: prolog, predicate

I created some predicate similar to that one in the (hopefully) minimal example I want to give you below. With that I wish to get the set `Z` in following logical way:

Given some universal set {peter, sandra} and some binary operator `l` and `x` (`l` stands for is love and `x` for equivalent) and some basic axioms (in form of variables), say

- `A l A`
- `(B l A) x (A l B)`

I now want to list all axioms which fully explain some specific one illustrated by our set and save the list of them in some variable. For that purpose I generated the predicate

```
find_axioms(Specific, BaseSet, Fullfill)
```

Aim:

The BaseSet is our list of possible axioms `[A l A, (B l A) x (A l B)]`
The Variable Fullfill should be some return-code, say Z
And Specific is some set of love-relations to checked by axioms, say e.g. [peter l anna, peter l peter].

Now if I these three arguments, say I call

```
find_axioms([(peter l anna), (peter l peter)], [(A l A), (B l A) x (A l B)], Z).
```

my expected output should be:

```
A = peter
Z = peter l peter
```

`axiom (B l A) x (A l B)` should not be part of that cause this template is not in our variable `Specific`, so it can be ignored in `Z`.

Now I tried to explain that with following statement of logic:

```
∀ x in Specific: x in BaseSet → x in Fullfill
```

I now expected, the code should be like that:

```
:-op(900, xfy, l).
:-op(900, xfy, x).


find_axioms(Specific, BaseSet, Fullfill) :-
    forall(member(X, Specific), 
        (member(X, BaseSet) -> member(X, Fullfill))).
```

But for some reason

```
find_axioms([(peter l anna), (peter l peter)], [(A l A), (B l A) x (A l B)], Z).
```

only gives output false and does not define the variables in the way I would expect. Some syntax like

```
(A l A) = (peter l peter)
```

instead gives me the correct output I expect:

```
A = peter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) is good to prove a relation or to produce some side effects (for example, when used with `write/1` or `assertz/1`). If you intend to create variable bindings, this predicate is inadequate (since it does not change any variable binding). Instead, you should use the predicate [findall/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) (see also [bagof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3) and [setof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)).

Thus, I think you can try something like this:

```
find_axioms(Specific, BaseSet, Fullfill) :-
    findall(X, 
            ( member(X, Specific), 
              member(X, BaseSet) ), 
            Fullfill).
```